# jquery masked input plugin to allow variable lengths?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The [masked input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin allows you to define constant-length masks. I am looking for a plugin with similar functionality that allows for variable length input.

A use-case for this would be currency entry. As user enters digits, the plugin would add thousands separators, decimal point and currency symbol where appropriate.

Does anyone know of anything that does currency, or even something more generic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found exactly what i needed for currency:

http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/priceformat

There are a bunch of examples at its homepage: http://www.jquerypriceformat.com/